How to sort correctly the processes hungry of ram?
With this cmd line I see processes and use of ram in mb
ps aux  | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}'  | sort -rn|less
The problem is the sort
9.95703 MB      /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
9.89062 MB      /usr/sbin/winbindd
9.76953 MB      /usr/sbin/winbindd
9.69922 MB      php-fpm:
9.69922 MB      php-fpm:
9.69531 MB      php-fpm:
9.69531 MB      php-fpm:
9.69531 MB      php-fpm:
93.4297 MB      db_arc1_FREE
9.31641 MB      winbindd:
9.31641 MB      /usr/sbin/snmpd

How to sort correctly so the output became like this?
93.4297 MB      db_arc1_FREE
9.95703 MB      /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
9.89062 MB      /usr/sbin/winbindd
9.76953 MB      /usr/sbin/winbindd
9.69922 MB      php-fpm:
9.69922 MB      php-fpm:
9.69531 MB      php-fpm:
9.69531 MB      php-fpm:
9.69531 MB      php-fpm:
9.31641 MB      winbindd:
9.31641 MB      /usr/sbin/snmpd


works for me.  Are you sure you included the -n in the command that produced the first output?   Also, this is easier with top, sort by RSS, RES, or VIRT as appropriate for your use case and version of top.

ps aux --sort=rss

or
ps aux --sort=%mem


Thanks, to get sorted from top to bottom ps aux --sort=-%mem
